# How to retrieve yarn's logs programmatically using java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I actually retrieve my spark application's logs on a linux shell with :

`yarn logs -applicationId applicationid`

Is there any way to retrieve it programmatically using java ?

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to do it programmatically using java, so i finally took a look at the code behind the command :

```
yarn logs -applicationId applicationid
```

which is in :

```
src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/cli/LogsCLI.java
```

I now retrieve the logs in a string (content). The code is:

```
String applicationId = "application_1492795815045_3940";
ApplicationId appId = appId = ConverterUtils.toApplicationId(applicationId);
LogCLIHelpers logCliHelper = new LogCLIHelpers();
Configuration config = new Configuration();
logCliHelper.setConf(config);
String appOwner = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getShortUserName();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
// Function to retrieve logs
logCliHelper.dumpAllContainersLogs(appId, appOwner, ps);
String content = new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(content)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Yarn 3.3 which can not pass the PrintStream to method `dumpAllContainersLogs `.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.  You can get most of the key information about an application via [YarnClient](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/client/api/YarnClient.html) and you can make rest calls to the [Spark History Server API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html).  The endpoint you're looking for here is

```
/applications/[base-app-id]/logs
```

Comment: `YarnClient` lets you retrieve some info about the app but unfortunately not the logs:(. And you can retrieve the logs using Spark's REST API method `/applications/[base-app-id]/logs` but the stdout, from my app at least, seems to be missing from those logs. And that's even though you can see the stdout when you use `yarn logs -applicationId <appid> -log_files stdout`. I really need a way to retrieve stdout programmatically from Java. Or maybe I need my app to log to Spark instead...

Answer (score 1):

**Your method in shell environment is correct!**

In my opinion, because yarn is already **an executable program** in your system.

To make current java process(i.e., current jvm) access and use it. You can start up **a new child process** to help you do the job.

Maybe the code followed will help you.

```
public class YarnLog {
    //
    public static void getYarnLog(String appid) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("yarn logs -applicationId %s", appid));
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**After the successful termination of this child process, you can use your specific logs as normal files in you current working directory**.